# how do use pseudonyms in query using alias with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I would like know, if it's possible to write a query using "`AS`" without to need to make alignment the queries using **MySQL**.

> Examples One (with alignment and sub queries within of main query)

```
SELECT ID FROM (
    SELECT ID, msisdn FROM (
        SELECT * FROM TT2
    ) AS T
) AS T
```

---

> Exemple Two (without alignment and sub queries out of main query)

```
SELECT name,LEFT(occupation,1) AS letter FROM OCCUPATIONS ORDER BY name AS tab1;

SELECT letter FROM tab1 ORDER BY letra ASC;
```

This **example two not work**, would be possible doing for other way?

> The main diference between example one and two is that in first case, the main query it has sub queries within from themselves and in second case, the sub queries they are out of the main query.

Maybe a option for this question, according with [this answer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/259744/como-usar-alias-em-mysql-sem-aninhamento-da-consulta/259749?noredirect=1#comment532985_259749):

```
With tab1 as (
SELECT name,LEFT(occupation,1) AS letra FROM OCCUPATIONS ORDER BY name
)

SELECT letra FROM tab1 ORDER BY letra ASC;
```

Someone has some other suggestion of how to do?

Comment: Depending on the use case, you can create a temporary table or a view.

Comment: You can't do CTE's in MySQL so as others are pointing out, a View or Temp Table would be more appropriate (short of a subquery like in your first not-quite-right-but-close-enough) example.

Comment: @clinomaniac Yes, I am trying to found a way of to process of queries with temporary table, but without to need create in fact, they are temporary, I am trying work with "AS".

Comment: There is no way to use it without having the data saved to the disk unless you want to use just one query in which it can be used as a subquery.

Comment: @clinomaniac Yes, I am wanting to use sub queries, but without to need alignment, equals example two.

Comment: @JonathasB.C. Unfortunately for you, until MySQL 8 *(which has Common Table Expressions)* you do not have the ability to declare a query *"expression"* on one *"line"* then use it on another *"line"*.  You need to create a real View *(then drop it afterwards)*, persist the data *(Create Table AS or similar)* or use inline views / sub-queries *(both names for the same thing, your Example 1)*.

Comment: Would be nice for a SQL Dialect to allow Temporary Views.  To use in multiple different statements in the same *script* / "procedure*.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Create Table As`(aka CTAs):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tab1 AS
SELECT name,LEFT(occupation,1) AS letter 
FROM OCCUPATIONS;

SELECT letter FROM tab1 ORDER BY letter ASC;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=efcf119938f53037afb3f2932a442529)**

Comment: Thanks for answer, but  Is possible to do without create table? using pseudonymous ? or aliase "AS"? temporary table?

Comment: @JonathasB.C. If you want to use it as 2 separate statements then answer is "no"

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT letter FROM (SELECT name, LEFT(occupation,1) AS letter FROM OCCUPATIONS) tab1 ORDER BY letter ASC;
```

Alignment is just for readability. You can choose to have your whole statement in one line which makes it hard to read.

Comment: Also...adding order by in both places will negate the effect of the first one.

Comment: Isn't that just "example one" but with single line formatting?  I believe the OP wants to be able to write SQL in a more "top down" style *(as opposed to "from the middle, then out")*.

Comment: You made me to perceive a mistake with the understanding of the ask, I confused the my understand about alignment with sub queries within main query, sorry.

Comment: @MatBailie My english is bad, sorry.

Comment: @JonathasB.C. Your English is better than most Americans' ;)